# HOWTO detect when JBOSS is fully up and running and ready to accept deployments?

Tags: jboss

I have a simple "sanity-check" webapp that I wish to deploy on a JBoss EAP server as soon as it is started.  But what does "started" mean?  If my script that calls the jboss cli is launched too soon after JBoss reports it's done, I get a message saying

```
  {"WFLYDC0074: Operation failed or was rolled back on all servers. Server failures:" => {"server-group" => {"main-server-group" => {"host" => {"master" => {"master-1-server-1" => "WFLYCTL0379: System boot is in process; execution of remote management operations is not currently available"}}}}}}
```

How can I detect that JBoss is **really** ready to handle deployments?

Alternatively, is there a mechanism by which I can autodeploy something on startup?

Comment: Tail the log file, there will be an entry along the line of "startup completed in _n_ seconds".

Comment: @Steve Cohen, did you figure out a better way to know when Jboss is really ready? I have the exact issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
  do
    wildflyStarted=$(grep -ic "Wildfly.*started in.*ms.*Started.*of.*services" /opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log)
    if [[ "$wildflyStarted" -eq "1" ]]; then
      break;
    else
      sleep 1;
    fi
  done

while true
  do
    ejbcaStatus=$(/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="cd deployment,cd ejbca.ear,read-attribute status")
    if [[ "$ejbcaStatus" -eq "OK" ]]; then
      break;
    else
      sleep 5;
    fi
  done
```

This script worked for me.